# What is the use of the following statement in python regular expression?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to python and i need to work on an existing python script. Can someone explain me what is the meaning of the following statement

```
pgre = re.compile("([^T]+)T([^\.]+)\.[^\s]+\s(\d+\.\d+):\s\[.+\]\s+(\d+)K->(\d+)K\((\d+)K\),\s(\d+\.\d+)\ssecs\]")
```

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/cE8rU2

Comment: Do you have any hint what kind of input could be matched with it? How is `pgre` used?

Comment: See also http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: There's a reason regular expressions are generally thought of as a write-only language.

Comment: This is the input that it is reading,


2013-08-28T08:59:09.683-0500: 6.055: [GC [PSYoungGen: 131072K->19202K(152896K)] 131072K->19274K(502464K), 0.0357220 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs]

it is the python script for GC analyzer

Answer (score 2):

You need to consult the references for the exact meanings of each part of that regular expression, but the basic purpose of it is to parse the GC logging. Each parenthesized part of the expression `()` is a group that matches a useful part of the GC line.

For example, the start of the regex `([^T]+)T` matches everything up to the first "T", and the grouped part returns the text before the "T", i.e. the date "2013-08-28"

The content of the group, `[^T]+` means "at least one character that is not a T"

Patterns in square brackets [] are *character classes* - consult the references in the comments above for details. Note that your input text contains literal square brackets, so the pattern handles those with the `\[` escape sequence - see below.

I think you can simplify `([^T]+)T` to just `(.+)T`, incidentally.

Other useful sub-patterns:

- `\s` matches whitespace
- `\d` matches numeric digits
- `\.`  `\(` and `\[` match literal periods, parentheses, and square braces, respectively, rather than interpreting them as special regex characters

Comment: Ok but i need to modify the script to a new format for GC, so how am i supposed to do it if i dont know what and how is currently implemented?

Comment: I think you will need to study the regex references before you can safely modify the script. The references already given explain all you need to know. Your regex looks intimidating, but it is built up of quite simple elements.

Comment: Now the new format of the input is 

2014-02-21T04:41:08.601-0500: 10.959: [GC2014-02-21T04:41:08.601-0500: 10.959: [ParNew: 1677824K->209663K(1887488K), 0.9136870 secs] 1677824K->270291K(3984640K), 0.9138940 secs] [Times: user=0.89 sys=0.06, real=0.91 secs]